# Writing a large XML file with Out Of Memory Error Java

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I am developing an app for android, I need to create a rather large XML file.

I have tried this with a DOM document however because it resides in memory it throws an 'out of memory' error.

Can someone suggest an alternative solution? This is a XML file create from scratch.

Comment: Does having chunks in memory works?

Comment: did you get a chance to check this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipbigdoc/index.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the XML to a Stream or Writer progressively as to traverse the data you want to turn into XML.  This way you don't need much more memory than the original data.

Comment: In the in end I used a writer, it was a little on the slow side but did the job. I managed to create a 700mb xml file. Thankyou to all, each answer was helpful!

Comment: I would make sure you are using a BufferedWriter. Without this it can be 10x slower.

Answer (score 1):

You will always go out of memory for Large Data size. How about dividing your Data and creating small chuncks and then appending all those together.

Or an other option is using SAX parser which consumes less  [memory](http://tech.inhelsinki.nl/2007-08-29/).

Answer (score 1):

Streaming XML is the way to go. The most 'vanilla' approach is probably using StAX: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html#bnbff